# How to resolve exception: Could not resolve placeholder in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I am deploying my web app in my local but for some reason `Spring` is throwing `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'safenet.username' in string value "${safenet.username}"` exception. I am clueless what to do?

stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'SafenetEncryptionProvider' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-config/spring-config.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'safenet.username' in string value "${safenet.username}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'safenet.username' in string value "${safenet.username}"
```

This is the bean

```
<bean id="SafenetEncryptionProvider" class="package.SafenetStringEncryptionProvider" init-method="initialize" destroy-method="destroy">
    <property name="username">
        <value>${safenet.username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${safenet.password}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="keyName">
        <value>${safenet.key}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="enabled">
        <value>${safenet.enabled}</value>
    </property>                 
</bean>
```

Am I missing anything?

Thanks...

Comment: There is no replacemant for the placeholder. Add it to your application properties.

Comment: Without the complete configuration is difficult to say! Do you have created a property-placeholder configuration?(https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-configuration.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-context-pphc)

Comment: I got it. I had to add some prpperties in catalina.properties file. Thanks all.