# BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name servletContainer

Tags: java, spring, maven

I work with a `Spring Boot` project that I could build properly. However, at the time of running the project with the command e.g 
`mvn spring-boot:run` I get the following error stack with `BeanCreationException` provided below,

```
2017-12-04 17:07:03.210 ERROR 2764 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletContainer' defined in com.quotecrunchers.email.HubSpotEmailApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory]: Factory method 'servletContainer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'BASE' in value "${BASE}"
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at com.quotecrunchers.email.HubSpotEmailApplication.main(HubSpotEmailApplication.java:58) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:527) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletContainer' defined in com.quotecrunchers.email.HubSpotEmailApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory]: Factory method 'servletContainer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'BASE' in value "${BASE}"
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:199) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
        ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory]: Factory method 'servletContainer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'BASE' in value "${BASE}"
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'BASE' in value "${BASE}"
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174) ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:236) ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210) ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveNestedPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:227) ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:84) ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:61) ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:527) ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at com.quotecrunchers.email.KeystoreDetailReader.createKeystoreDetails(KeystoreDetailReader.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.quotecrunchers.email.HubSpotEmailApplication.servletContainer(HubSpotEmailApplication.java:70) [classes/:na]
        at com.quotecrunchers.email.HubSpotEmailApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$da41a424.CGLIB$servletContainer$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.quotecrunchers.email.HubSpotEmailApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$da41a424$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a6492ef3.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        at com.quotecrunchers.email.HubSpotEmailApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$da41a424.servletContainer(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
        ... 26 common frames omitted

[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:527)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletContainer' defined in com.quotecrunchers.email.HubSpotEmailApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory]: Factory method 'servletContainer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'BASE' in value "${BASE}"
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
        at com.quotecrunchers.email.HubSpotEmailApplication.main(HubSpotEmailApplication.java:58)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletContainer' defined in com.quotecrunchers.email.HubSpotEmailApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory]: Factory method 'servletContainer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'BASE' in value "${BASE}"
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:199)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:162)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory]: Factory method 'servletContainer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'BASE' in value "${BASE}"
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'BASE' in value "${BASE}"
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:236)
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210)
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveNestedPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:227)
        at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:84)
        at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:61)
        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:527)
        at com.quotecrunchers.email.KeystoreDetailReader.createKeystoreDetails(KeystoreDetailReader.java:17)
        at com.quotecrunchers.email.HubSpotEmailApplication.servletContainer(HubSpotEmailApplication.java:70)
        at com.quotecrunchers.email.HubSpotEmailApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$da41a424.CGLIB$servletContainer$0(<generated>)
        at com.quotecrunchers.email.HubSpotEmailApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$da41a424$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a6492ef3.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
        at com.quotecrunchers.email.HubSpotEmailApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$da41a424.servletContainer(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 26 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.367 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-04T17:07:03+06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 33M/490M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.8.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project HubSpotEmail: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletContainer' defined in com.quotecrunchers.email.HubSpotEmailApplication: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory]: Factory method 'servletContainer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'BASE' in value "${BASE}" -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

The relevant portion of the code is provided below with the `servletContainer` method mentioned in the error stack,

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
public abstract class HubSpotEmailApplication
        implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>, ApplicationContextAware {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private KeystoreDetailReader keystoreDetailReader;

    private boolean hasCertificate = false;

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private KeystoreFacade keystore;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HubSpotEmailApplication.class, args);
    }

    /**
     * This bean configures either an http or an https Tomcat Connector.
     * Whether an http or https connector is configured depends on
     * whether a valid SSL certificate is available.
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
        KeystoreDetails keystoreDetails = keystoreDetailReader.createKeystoreDetails();
        keystore = new KeystoreFacade(keystoreDetails);

        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = null;

        try {

            hasCertificate = isValidCertificateAvailable();

            log.info("SSL Certificate in place: " + hasCertificate);
            log.info("Https protocol requested: " + useHttps());
            if (useHttps() && hasCertificate) {
                tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
                    @Override
                    protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                        SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                        securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                        SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                        collection.addPattern("/*");
                        //collection.removePattern("/.well-known/acme-challenge/*");
                        securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                        context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
                    }
                };
                tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createSslConnector(keystoreDetails));

            } else {
                tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
            }
        } catch (KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | IOException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }

        return tomcat;
    }

 // more code goes

}
```

The `application.yml` file is provided below with the modified keys,

```
hubspot:
  url: http://api.hubapi.com/
  fileUpload: filemanager/api/v2/files
  createFolder: filemanager/api/v2/folders
  key: c1488a5b-4c9a-4f80-bb1e-some_key
  emailId: some_id
  singleSendApi: email/public/v1/singleEmail/send
  pdfTemplateUrl:https://ddddrtrt.hubererespot.net/hubfs/3955925/mobile-calc-resources/eclipx-email.pdf

logging:
  level: debug
domain: test.api.thescene.co
keystore-folder: ${BASE}
admin-username: bravo
admin-password: bravo
server.port: 80
server.protocol: http

ssl:
  key-store: lets-encrypt-keystore.jks
  key-store-password: flexigroup
  key-password: flexigroup
  key-alias: test.api.thescene.co
  # below value can be staging or production. Let's encrypt only issue 5 production certs per week so use them carefully
  lets-encrypt: production

spreadsheet:
  user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11
  url: https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/439943/LoanCalculatorTX/{0}.xls?update={1}
  suffix: .xls
```

It seems that the issue started from the `keystore-folder: ${BASE}` line and the relevant part of the error stack,

```
Factory method 'servletContainer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'BASE' in value "${BASE}"
```

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Post the full stacktrace instead of a snippet.

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46326438/how-to-resolve-exception-could-not-resolve-placeholder-in-spring?

Comment: @M.Deinum I have provided the full error stack

Comment: `Could not resolve placeholder 'BASE' in value "${BASE}"` ???

Comment: That seems correct, I also provided the `application.yml` file with the updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I's obvious that  a key named `BASE` should be provided.You can refer to [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-placeholders-in-properties)

Comment: This is my question: how do I provide the `keystore-folder` value? I don't find the way out here. Do you have any example for that?

Comment: It seems you don't need a Tomcat Server with https enabled at all,just provide an empty  value ,or any,  instead of a placeholder `${BASE}`